# Cocoapods seems to install wrong pod version

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, cocoapods

Cocoapods seems to install a wrong pod version.

Here is an example line from my `pubspec.yaml`:

```
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
```

When running `pod install`, this is what I see:

```
 Installing webview_flutter (0.0.1)
```

In my `flutter/.pub_cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/` I see the only the following versions:

```
webview_flutter-0.3.24
webview_flutter-1.0.7
```

When building with XCode, I get a few warnings from `webview_flutter` that point to the correct `1.0.7` version, so it seems the right pod is being used despite the cocoapods output. However, this is really confusing. Any thoughts how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried re-installing cocoapods, deintegrating pods and building again, cleaning, updating pod repo, deleted Podfile.lock etc usual suspects.

Here's my environment:

````
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H15 darwin-x64, locale en-FI)
    • Flutter version 1.22.5 at /Users/ilonamooney/Documents/dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 7891006299 (10 days ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
    • Engine revision ae90085a84
    • Dart version 2.10.4

 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ilonamooney/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/ilonamooney/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.3, Build version 12C33
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.0

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Ilona’s iPhone (mobile) • a12e6e165529c7307dfdb723f37e02f3901f17d0 • ios • iOS 14.2```
````

Comment: Try `pod update` instead of `pod install`

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?